# C++ QT: undefined reference `_imp___ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci' in CLion

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to run some QT in C++ in CLion so I tried running this code, already written and working from sources:

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QFormLayout>

int editExample(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w{};
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    QLabel label("&Hello ");
    label.setBuddy(&lineEdit);
    QVBoxLayout layout{ &w };
    layout.addWidget(&label);
    layout.addWidget(&lineEdit);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

int buttonExample(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // button - example
    QPushButton button("&This is a button.\nPush it!");

    // set tooltip
    button.setToolTip("Look! I'm a button!");
    button.setToolTipDuration(2000);

    // set font
    QFont font("Courier", 50, 10, true);
    button.setFont(font);

    // set background image
    QIcon icon("Peacock.JPG");
    button.setIcon(icon);
    button.setIconSize(QSize(400, 400));

    button.show();

    return a.exec();
}

int listExample(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QListWidget list;
    new QListWidgetItem("Gone With the Wind", &list);
    new QListWidgetItem("The Three Musketeers", &list);

    // add a QListWidgetItem, with a different font
    QListWidgetItem *item3 = new QListWidgetItem("The Wizard of Oz");
    QFont font("Courier", 20, 10, true);
    item3->setFont(font);
    list.insertItem(0, item3);

    list.show();

    return a.exec();
}

int hBoxLayout(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget wnd{};
    QHBoxLayout hLay{};
    QPushButton btn1{ "Button 1" };
    QPushButton btn2{ "Button 2" };
    QPushButton btn3{ "Button 3" };
    hLay.addWidget(&btn1);
    hLay.addWidget(&btn2);
    hLay.addWidget(&btn3);
    wnd.setLayout(&hLay);
    wnd.show();

    return a.exec();
}

int vBoxLayout(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *wnd = new QWidget{};
    QVBoxLayout *vLay = new QVBoxLayout{};
    QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton{ "Button 1" };
    QPushButton *btn2 = new QPushButton{ "Button 2" };
    QPushButton *btn3 = new QPushButton{ "Button 3" };
    vLay->addWidget(btn1);
    vLay->addWidget(btn2);
    vLay->addWidget(btn3);
    wnd->setLayout(vLay);
    wnd->show();

    return a.exec();
}

int formLayout(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout{};

    // create labels and textboxes
    QLineEdit* nameTextBox = new QLineEdit{};
    QLabel* nameLabel = new QLabel{ "&Name:" };
    nameLabel->setBuddy(nameTextBox);

    QLineEdit* ageTextBox = new QLineEdit{};
    QLabel* ageLabel = new QLabel{ "&Age:" };
    ageLabel->setBuddy(ageTextBox);

    QLineEdit* emailTextBox = new QLineEdit{};
    QLabel* emailLabel = new QLabel{ "&Email:" };
    emailLabel->setBuddy(emailTextBox);

    formLayout->addRow(nameLabel, nameTextBox);
    formLayout->addRow(ageLabel, ageTextBox);
    formLayout->addRow(emailLabel, emailTextBox);

    QWidget *wnd = new QWidget{};
    wnd->setLayout(formLayout);
    wnd->show();

    return a.exec();
}

int gridLayout(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout{};

    // add some buttons
    gridLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Add"), 0, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Delete"), 0, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Update"), 0, 2);
    gridLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Filter"), 1, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Sort"), 2, 0, 1, 3); // row span = 1, column span = 3

    QWidget *wnd = new QWidget{};
    wnd->setLayout(gridLayout);
    wnd->show();

    return a.exec();
}

int multipleLayouts(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *wnd = new QWidget{};
    QVBoxLayout *vL = new QVBoxLayout{};
    wnd->setLayout(vL);

    //create an information widget, with a QFormLayout
    QWidget *details = new QWidget{};
    QFormLayout *fL = new QFormLayout{};
    details->setLayout(fL);
    QLabel *labelName = new QLabel{ "&Name" };
    QLineEdit *textBoxName = new QLineEdit{};
    labelName->setBuddy(textBoxName);

    fL->addRow(labelName, textBoxName);

    QLabel *labelAge = new QLabel{ "&Age" };
    QLineEdit *textBoxAge = new QLineEdit{};
    labelAge->setBuddy(textBoxAge);
    fL->addRow(labelAge, textBoxAge);

    //add the information widget to the window
    vL->addWidget(details);

    // create a widget with two buttons for two possible actions: Save or Cancel
    // this widget will have a QHBoxLayout
    QWidget* actions = new QWidget{};
    QHBoxLayout* hL = new QHBoxLayout{};
    QPushButton *store = new QPushButton{ "&Save" };
    QPushButton *cancel = new QPushButton{ "&Cancel" };
    hL->addWidget(store);
    hL->addWidget(cancel);
    actions->setLayout(hL);

    // add the actions widget to the window
    vL->addWidget(actions);

    //show window
    wnd->show();

    return a.exec();
}

// create the same GUI with absolute positioning and with layouts
int createAbsolute(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget* main = new QWidget{};
    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("Name:", main);
    lbl->setGeometry(10, 10, 40, 20);
    QLineEdit* txt = new QLineEdit(main);
    txt->setGeometry(60, 10, 100, 20);
    main->show();
    main->setWindowTitle("Absolute");

    return a.exec();
}

int createWithLayout(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget* main = new QWidget{};
    QFormLayout *fL = new QFormLayout(main);
    QLabel* lbl = new QLabel("Name:", main);
    QLineEdit* txt = new QLineEdit(main);
    fL->addRow(lbl, txt);
    main->show();
    main->setWindowTitle("Layout");
    //fix the height to the "ideal" height
    main->setFixedHeight(main->sizeHint().height());    // Sets both the minimum and maximum heights of the widget to the given height.
    // sizeHint - holds the recommended size for the widget.

    return a.exec();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return editExample(argc, argv);

//  return buttonExample(argc, argv);
//  return listExample(argc, argv);
//
//  return hBoxLayout(argc, argv);
//  return vBoxLayout(argc, argv);
//  return formLayout(argc, argv);
//  return gridLayout(argc, argv);
//  return multipleLayouts(argc, argv);
//
//  return createAbsolute(argc, argv);
//  return createWithLayout(argc, argv);
}
```

but I get a whole lot of compile errors such as:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'
```

for each of the Q classes, and I'm not really sure why, because I followed the footsteps in CMakeLists as well, here's my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(qt)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.15.2\\mingw81_64\\")

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(qt
        main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qt Qt5::Widgets)
```

The code is not really that relevant I think, because it's something wrong with QT but I can't seem to figure out what - can someone help me fix the problem? I tried adding QT to the path, but to no success

Comment: clion doesn't really have anything to do with linking errors. You need to check your IDE and Qt setup.

Comment: I was just giving all details just in case

Comment: Well, obviously you aren't linking something you should be linking with. Probably something in the `target_link_libraries` is missing.

Comment: add `#include <QApplication>`